# func abbreviation(for: Date) -> String? function in swift

Tags: swift, timezone

I m not able to understand this function "func abbreviation(for: Date) -> String?" available on TimeZone in swift. What it does. is there any tutorials that explain it in details with example?

```
 let time1 = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Chicago")
 print(time1?.abbreviation(for: Date()))
```

if I call .abbreviation() method, how device time/region/language affect the result.
I m getting different result based on region and language.

If region is austrilia output is "GMT-6".
If region is Canada output is "CST"

Comment: Surely you have read its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone/2293351-abbreviation)? What exactly didn't you understand?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer that you expect here. "Yes, device region and language does affect the result"? It appears that you already know that. It's just a simple fact that different timezones are called differently in different parts of the world.

Comment: is time zone for identifier "America/Chicago" will be called differently in different parts of the world ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If region is austrilia output is "GMT-6". If region is Canada output is "CST"

This is quite reasonable. If you search for "CST" in [this list](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/), you will find that it is an abbreviation for quite a lot of timezones.

Specifically, CST stands for both Central Standard Time in America *and* Central Standard Time in Australia (the latter can also be abbreviated as ACST).

If the system region is Australia, then `abbreviation` outputting "CST" for `America/Chicago` would be rather confusing. An Australian would see "CST" and go "Ah that's *Australian* Central Standard Time" (at least that's what iOS thinks). Clearly not what you mean. Therefore, it resorts to the more accurate but less meaningful "UTC-6".

Another example is that the same timezone is called differently depending on the language. If the phone's region is in Canada, `America/Toronto`, for example, would have different abbreviations depending on the phone's language. In English, it is EST at the time of writing - Eastern Standard Time. In French (Canada), it is Heure Normale de l'Est (HNE). [See other timezone abbreviations and names in French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32194/how-to-translate-time-zones-to-canadian-french).

The output of `abbreviation(for:)` is meant to be human readable, not so much machine-readable. It tries to produce an abbreviation that is understandable to people living in the system region, speaking the system language. For the most part, it is a black box. Don't think too much about it.

Comment: This is a great answer. I can't find in the docs where it says the output of `abbreviation` is localised so this answer is extra valuable. Thank you