# Getting timezone abbreviations in Swift

Tags: swift, nstimezone

I am trying to retrieve the timezone abbreviations of the local time zone by using the following code.

```
private func getLocalTimezone() -> String {
   guard let localTimezone =  TimeZone.current.abbreviation() else {
     return ""
   }
   return localTimezone
 }
```

But when I am in Indian time zone I am always getting GMT+5:30 where I need it as IST. Its coming correctly when I am in CST or PST. Can anyone please suggest a way to reach to the solution for this issue.
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because time zone abbreviations are locale sensitive. IST only means India Standard Time (`Asia/Kolkata`) in India. In other parts of the world, it could mean Israel Standard Time, or Irish Standard/Summer Time. Here's a [site](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/) that shows you the list of abbreviations. You can see for yourself how ambiguous they can be.

This is why [`abbreviation()` takes into account the region of your phone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65805999/5133585), i.e. this setting:

[image]

`abbreviation()` ***will*** give you "IST" if your device's region is India. If your phone is somewhere else, it shows "GMT+5:30" because that is the safest, most unambiguous option.

If you want it to output IST no matter where your device is, you need to hard code this by creating a dictionary of time zone identifiers to abbreviations that you want. There is a built in `abbreviationDictionary` that goes the other way - abbreviations to identifiers. You can search it, and it will work for IST (`Asia/Kolkata`), but might not work for whatever other time zone that you are interested in.

```
let abbreviation = TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary
    .first(where: { $1 == TimeZone.current.identifier })?.key
```

and I'm not sure whether the contents of this dictionary will stay the same in future versions of iOS. Use it at your own risk.